# How to change Azure Data Studio result pane default rows limit (for Extenstion Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure, azure-data-studio

When I run a query in Azure Data Studio, instead of writing limit keyword everytime in the query. Is it possible to set the default value to some number , so that Results windows shows only that number of rows from the top.
As of now it is displaying all the records which takes quite some time for some tables.

```
select * from Table limit 200; // I don't want to use limit keyword everytime.
```

Comment: The mssql extension has a `mssql.query.rowCount` setting, but (unfortunately) I see no such similar setting for the pgsql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, **Agreed with Thoms A setting row count by default is only supported for MsSQL not PostgreSQL.**

**The only way to get Results windows shows only that number of rows from the top is use query `LIMIT` and `FETCH first N rows only`.**

- Using `FETCH first N rows only`

```sql
select  * from table FETCH first 10 rows only
```

Comment: As @ThomA mentioned the above solution works for mssql but not for psgsql extension which supports to run postgres queries.

Comment: ok Will check it and update it accordingly.

Comment: Update the answer according to ask as there are no similar settings for PostgreSQL extension in Azure data studio.